# set date and set time in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Is there an inbuilt function in postgres that allows the user to set the date and time? I am going through the manual, but there are just functions to format the date and time but nothing that I can see to set the date and time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL uses the server's time, which can not be changed without escalating privileges. (meaning the answer is **no**).